# vs2010 breaks the content of parameters.xml

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters, msdeploy

I've got the file Parameters.xml that contains the following

```
<parameter name="Identity Suffix" description="Suffix of the identity services of the environment"   tags="" >
    <parameterEntry kind="TextFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="__IDENTITY_SUFFIX__"/>
    <parameterValidation type="AllowEmpty" /> 
</parameter>
```

After I run Build deployment package the output file does not contains any parameterValidation and I have to edit the file manually. How to fix this behavior ?

Comment: Thank you. How to format the xml in the message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS supports two schemes:

```
<parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty" />
<parameterValidation type="AllowEmpty" />
```

VS supports only first one